# Are there any hacks to resolve circular reference problems?

Tags: c#

I inherited a code base that wasn't well thought out, and am running into some circular reference problems. My team doesn't currently have the time or resources to do a huge refactor, so I was wondering if there was some switch that I could flip that says "build these two dlls atomically."

A simplified example:

```
DLL D0:
    class A1 -> References B1
    class B1 -> References A1
```

Class A1 and B1 have references to each other, and as they're in the same DLL, this is fine - but they don't have much in common so I want to break them out into separate dlls.

However, the following is impossible because of a circular reference problem:

```
DLL D1: class A1 -> References D2.B1
DLL D2: class B1 -> References D1.A1
```

I want to be able to tell MSBuild to build (D1+D2) as if all of the code were in a single dll. Is there anything I can do here or do I follow SOP and "hack it in?"

Disclaimer: I understand this implies I have a much bigger problem with my model (the most glaring is an improper use of interfaces), but in the small company, real world scenarios dictate that I bend over backwards to fix production bugs at the expense of best practices.

Comment: What is the advantage of breaking them into separate physical files? You can have them in separate projects and use MSBuild to construct a single .netModule that can then be compiled into an executable... but going the other way... not so much without refactoring to interfaces and dependency injection.

Comment: It sounds like hacks are what lead to your issue of circular references, and they will not be part of a real solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> My team doesn't currently have the time or resources to do a huge
>   refactor

so... DO NOT DO THIS:

> but they don't have much in common so I want to break them out into
>   separate dlls.

Leave it alone until you can apply significant refactoring to the whole solution.

This is a case where refactoring an organizational peeve will force a huge amount of refactoring down stream. And you have much bigger problems to deal with. I've been there. I feel for you. Good luck mate.